# SQL Server: Self Join query; select only records with matching first name WITHOUT a where statement

Tags: sql-server, select, self-join

I am completely new to SQL Server. I'm stuck on a lab question. I cannot use a WHERE statement to limit the results. I attached the directions I was given below. Expected result should return 6 rows. I am currently returning 122 rows.We are using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. We are pulling from a large, pre-configured database with thousands of records.

This is the quoted text from the lab.

> Write a SELECT statement that returns three columns:
>
> - VendorID From the Vendors table
> - VendorName From the Vendors table
> - Contact Name Alias for VendorContactFName and VendorContactLName, with a space in between.
>
> Write a SELECT statement which compares each vendor whose VendorContactFName has the same first name as another VendorContactFName. In other words, find all the different Vendors whose VendorContactFName have the same first name. 
>   Compound JOIN Condition.
>
> No WHERE condition. Sort the final result set by Contact Name (6 rows returned)
>
> Hint: Use a self-join & correlation names; Ex: The Vendor table is both V1 & V2. QUALIFY ALL COLUMN NAMES in the query including those in the SELECT statement

This is what I have come up with so far, but can't figure out how to limit the records without a WHERE statement. I may have excess code that I don't need here, or missing code that I do need.

Here's the code I came up with to start.

```
SELECT  
    V1.VendorID AS VendorID, V1.VendorName AS VendorName,
    V1.VendorContactFName  + ' ' +  V1.VendorContactLName AS [Contact Name] 
FROM 
    Vendors AS V1 
JOIN 
    Vendors AS V2 ON (V1.VendorContactFName = V2.VendorContactFName) 
                  AND (V1.VendorID = V2.VendorID)
ORDER BY 
    [Contact Name];
```

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qHcp.png)

[DB Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slnXi.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Chris. Your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed. Some sample data and an expected result, especially, would be helpful.

Comment: It's the logic that's not clear. "I have to only return records with matching first names in the contact name field." So `ID1|Bob|Smith` "matches" `ID2|Bob|Somebodyelseski`? Hardly seems like a useful data set.

Comment: I agree the resulting data set makes no sense, but that's what the professor wants...

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also hits googling 'stackexchange homework'--explain how you got your query. PS The assignment result description is poor. "Compares" is vague & inappropriate to describe a result rather than a process. "Different" is not helpful. (It's probably trying to say something about distinct rows.) PS What columns does the assignment say to return?

Comment: Nowhere in your quoted block does it say your prof demands 6 records? Your professor asked for all vendors who share a first name with another vendor- why did you make the last name a join condition too? Do not use DISTINCT until you know what you're doing and why - it is NEVER the solution to duplicate records created by a join Cartesian. Always use explicit INNER, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, FULL OUTER join qualifiers. Typically table names are not aliased with AS but column names are. Prefer use of CONCAT to concatemate strings rather than + because it handles NULL more logically

Comment: @CaiusJard Just noticed the asker dropped the last name comparison. PS Distinct removes duplicate rows. When that is what one wants it is appropriate.

Comment: I've qualified my distinct comment

Comment: @CaiusJard My comment stands. Don't know what distinction you are trying to make.

Comment: Your statement is too loose. If a badly written join causes a Cartesian product the answer is to correct the join rather than have the database go to the effort of creating X duplicate records then unique them again. Saying distinct is appropriate for removing duplicates is true in the sense that there may naturally be repeated records in a table that cannot be removed another way (arguable that the db design should be improved to remove them) but I'd never advise a newbie that it's a universally acceptable way to clobber duplicate rows that crept into their query..

Comment: Please include relevant text from links in your question, including output & DDL & code for input. [mcve]--that means cut & paste & runnable text plus clear specification & explanation. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: After dropping DISTINCT and changing the V1.VendiorID "=" V2.VendorID to not equal to "<>", my problem is solved. I am very new to coding and forums alike and we have only learned some very basic code so far. Thank you all for the input and advice! I have much to learn stil.

Comment: I rolled back to remove your "solved" & return your links. Please don't add "solved", acceptance indicates that. Please avoid tags in titles. The links are better than nothing, they're just the wrong something. If you had a MCVE they would be redundant here. But you don't. See the [help] links. Google 'stackexchange notifications' re using @ to notify one non-poster commenter of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update the JOIN condition, FirstName should match between V1 and V2, but vendorId should be different. Also use `CONCAT` function for Contact name

```
SELECT DISTINCT V1.VendorID AS VendorID, 
       V1.VendorName AS VendorName,
       CONCAT(V1.VendorContactFName, ' ', V1.VendorContactLName)
        AS [Contact Name] 
FROM Vendors AS V1 JOIN Vendors AS V2 
    ON  (V1.VendorContactFName = V2.VendorContactFName) AND
        (V1.VendorID <> V2.VendorID)
ORDER BY [Contact Name]
```